# Samsung tv n5300 (2019 model) developer mode

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

When I press 12345 on the App screen for going into the developer mode, the screen accepts only four numbers . Accordingly I am not able to get the developer mode. Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Plz refer below guide.
https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-device.html
You should press 12345 in the 'Apps'